# How do I reference a field value when updating records using Waterline ORM

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to store a hierarchical structure using the Nested Set Model technique. I'm using Waterline ORM for node to query and update my database. How would I model the following query using Waterline?

UPDATE MyTable SET counter=counter+2 WHERE id > 4 AND id < 17;

I'm aware of MyTable.update(...) but I'm not sure how to reference an existing column value in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to reference existing field values in a Waterline `update` query, although it's a feature that's certainly been discussed.

In the meantime, if you don't want to follow a two-step process (`MyTable.find` followed by a loop and `.save()` for each instance), then you'll need to use native DB methods to accomplish this.  For `sails-mysql` and `sails-postgresql` adapters, that means using [`.query()`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/query.html):

```
MyTable.query("UPDATE MyTable SET counter=counter+2 WHERE id > 4 AND id < 17", 
              function(err, results) {...});
```

For the `sails-mongo` adapter, the analogous method is [.native()](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/native.html).